# Printing out extended ascii characters from an array

Tags: c, arrays, extended-ascii

So I am trying to print out an alphabet with some extended special characters but all I get is warnings and wrong letter
`warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`

The array

```
char letters[30] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c','č','ć', 'd','dž','đ', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'r', 's','š', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'z', 'ž' };

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
     printf("%c", letters[i]);
```

Comment: Please post your entire program.

Comment: `'dž'`? That's not a single character.

Comment: `'č'` --> `"č"[0], "č"[1]`, same for the rest of multibyte characters

Comment: You need "wide chars" in some incarnation, maybe POSIX `<wchar.h>`? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/wchar.h.html

Comment: Luka Milicevic, Does `wchar_t letters[] = {L'a', L'b', L'c', L'č', L'ć'};
  for (int i = 0; letters[i]; i++) {
    wprintf(L"%c", letters[i]);
  }` work for you?

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

You aren't going to be able to print out those non-ASCII characters with printf as they are currently formatted. Those don't even appear to be extended ASCII.

To see what characters are printable simply run the code provided in this post [ASCII Print Function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472581/printing-chars-and-their-ascii-code-in-c)

To read more about this you can view this post on printing non-ascii characters: [Printing Non-Ascii in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050899/how-to-print-non-ascii-characters-in-c)